# jQuery setting input using val() and activating change()

Tags: jquery

I have a large number of color selectors that input the value into a input field:

```
<input type="text" class="colour_picker"/>
```

Now when I prepopulate the fields, I want to use something like:

```
$(document).on("change", ".colour_picker",function(){

$(this).css("background-color", "#"+$(this).val());
});
```

However, this does not fire, I fugured out that I would need to call .change() after setting .val(), however is there an easier way to do this? I have coded thousands of lines of JS for this and don't really feel like going through them all finding all of the pre-population scripts and modifying them.

**EDIT: Here's a fiddle to show an example of the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/kj5sjs22/1/**

Comment: Can you make a demo of it.?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kj5sjs22/1/

Comment: change event on input raise after lost focus, so if you want see result when enter value you need use events like `keyup`, `keydown` or possibly [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)

Comment: @Grundy I change the value via val("sdfd"); which doesn't fire either one of them.

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius yep, in case where you manually change value with `val` function you need manually call change handler

Comment: Is there another way? Binding the BG change to .val() change or something?

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius, nope, if you do something manually, you need raise all event manually too

Comment: Ah thats unfortunate, surprising that jquery hasn't developed a method to avoid this.

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius it just standard logic

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius for quick fix you can after all prepopulating input select it and call change for all it like `$('.colour_picker').change()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Onchange* only fires when a user types a text and, then, the input lose focus.
It's not your case. You must trigger the event.

```
$(".colour_picker").val("000000").trigger('change');
```

Regards.

Comment: You didn't understand the question. I want to change it via actual JS, not input and then fire the onchange

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can not change the value via JS and fire the event automatically. So, What do you want?

Comment: ... I was looking if there was a way to do it, whilst you were giving me code for what I already had. Thanks for your input tho.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$(document).on("change", ".colour_picker",function(){
 $(this).css({"background-color":"#"+$(this).val()});
});
```

or

```
$(".colour_picker").keyup(function(){
 $(this).css({"background-color":"#"+$(this).val()});
});
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question. I want to change it via actual JS, not input and then fire the onchange.